# Prove that $10^n + 1 \equiv 0 \ \mod \ 1 \ldots 1, n \geqslant 2$ has no solutions.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $$10^n + 1 \equiv 0 \ \mod \ 1 \ldots 1 = \dfrac{10^k-1}{9}, k \geqslant 3,  n \geqslant 2$$ has no solutions. Where the number of units is greater than or equal to $3$.

Comment: I will be glad to any hints.

Comment: Do you mean like $10^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{11}$, or $10^3+1\equiv 0\pmod{111}$? Because that doesn't seem true.

Comment: What is $1\dots1$?

Comment: $ 1 \ldots 1 = \dfrac{10^k - 1}{9}, k \geqslant 2.$

Comment: $10^2 + 1 \equiv 2 \ \mod \ 11$, $10^3 + 1 \equiv 2 \ \mod 111$...

Comment: Yes, I mean what you wrote.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $10^n + 1 \equiv 0 \ \mod \ 1 \ldots 1 = \dfrac{10^n-1}{9}, n \geqslant 2$?

Comment: As formulated, the claim is false.

Comment: @Peter can you give a counterexample?

Comment: $11\mid 1001$ , for example.

Comment: Oh, sorry, $k \geqslant 3.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m=\frac{10^k-1}{9}$ so that $10^k=9m+1\equiv 1\pmod m$.
Let $n=qk+r$ with $0\leq r<k$.

Then
$$10^n=(10^k)^q10^r\equiv 10^r\pmod m.$$
If $10^r+1\equiv 0\pmod m$, then $m|(10^r+1)$ hence for $k\geq 3$ we get the contradiction
$$10^{k-1}+1<m\leq 10^r+1\leq 10^{k-1}+1.$$